# How to return an abstract class with a generic type?

Tags: c#

if I have the following abstract and concrete classes

```
public abstract class OpStrategy<T>
{
    public abstract bool Apply(T a, T b);
}
public class EqConcreteStrategy : OpStrategy<int>
{
    public override bool Apply(int a, int b)
    {
        return a.Equals(b);
    }
}
public class NeqConcreteStrat : OpStrategy<string>
{
    public override bool Apply(string a, string b)
    {
        return !a.Equals(b);
    }
}
```

I want to create a factory method that will take in a string and return one of the concrete implementation classes above but not quite sure how to do it. I tried the following (commented line is another thing I tried), but both result in one compilation error or another.

```
//public static OperatorStrategy<T> GetStrategy<T>(string operatorType)
public static OperatorStrategy GetStrategy(string operatorType)
{
    switch (operatorType)
    {
        case "eq":
            return new EqConcreteStrategy();
        case "neq":
            return new NeqConcreteStrategy();
    }

    return null;
}
```

My goal is to be able to do something like below

```
var strategy = GetStrategy("eq");
var results = strategy.Apply(a, b);
```

I feel like this should be doable somehow but this is the first time I have had to do it with a generic type. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: How about `public static OpStrategy<object> GetStrategy(string operatorType)`?

Comment: Literally what @Sweeper said is the only modification you need

Comment: Thanks sweeper I will give that a shot. As for not needing generics I just used the object type as part of the example, the actual implementation will have different types (string, int, DateTime, etc.)

Comment: Gave it a shot and it works for any concrete class that has the generic type of object but not for other types.

Comment: Introduce a new `Type`, maybe an interface. That way you can hide the generic details from callers who don't know, or can't know, what those details are.

Comment: Remember - `var` is a *compile time* construct that tells the compiler to figure out the type. Without knowing or inspecting the internals of `GetStrategy`, can *you* tell me what the type of `strategy` is in your final code sample, based on just the code there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to do exactly as you want.

I can suggest the following option. Perhaps it will suit you.

```
// The type of operation is defined here.
var strategy = GetStrategy("eq");

// The type of values is defined here.
strategy.Apply(1, 2);
strategy.Apply("1", "2");


static OpStrategy? GetStrategy(string operatorType)
{
    return operatorType switch
    {
        "eq"  => new EqConcreteStrategy(),
        "neq" => new NeqConcreteStrategy(),
        _     => null
    };
}

abstract class OpStrategy
{
    public abstract bool Apply<T>(T a, T b);
}

class EqConcreteStrategy : OpStrategy
{
    public override bool Apply<T>(T a, T b) => a.Equals(b);
}

class NeqConcreteStrategy : OpStrategy
{
    public override bool Apply<T>(T a, T b) => !a.Equals(b);
}
```

The class itself is not generic.
Only the `Apply` method is generic.

Comment: Thank you, this looks like a good approach. I was going to remove all the generics in favor of just an Apply(object a, object b) and then do some type casting, but I think your solution is cleaner.

Comment: Also, want to mention another thing I just thought of. I could return a dynamic from the GetStrategy method. I would lose the compile time checks, but it would allow me to keep the generic type on the class instead of the method.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
public static OpStrategy<object> GetStrategy(string operatorType)
{
    switch (operatorType)
    {
        case "eq":
            return new EqConcreteStrategy();
        case "neq":
            return new NeqConcreteStrategy();
    }

    return null;
}
```

But why do you use 'object' for the generic type?
This seems like a more meaningful implementation to me:

```
public static OpStrategy<T> GetStrategy<T>(string operatorType)
{
    switch (operatorType)
    {
        case "eq":
            return new EqConcreteStrategy<T>();
        case "neq":
            return new NeqConcreteStrategy<T>();
    }

    return null;
}

public abstract class OpStrategy<T>
{
    public abstract bool Apply(T a, T b);
}

public class EqConcreteStrategy<T> : OpStrategy<T>
{
    public override bool Apply(T a, T b)
    {
        return a.Equals(b);
    }
}

public class NeqConcreteStrategy<T> : OpStrategy<T>
{
    public override bool Apply(T a, T b)
    {
        return !a.Equals(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I used the object class as more of an example, the actual implementation I will have different types (string, int, DateTime, etc.). I will try with the object as you and sweeper mentioned.

Comment: I tried it with the object, but it only works for concrete classes that had the object type. I edited the original question to remove the object class just to make it more clear that I am not trying to use generics with only object types.